# Работа со спрайтами

Tags: c#, unity3d, спрайт

Как взять Sprite из Spritesheet через Resources.Load(path); язык c#

Answer (score 0):

```
Sprite[] sprites = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>(path);
Sprite targetSprite = sprites[3];
```

Нашел решение сам, вопрос закрыт.